# Is there a way to use dictionaries in python to input a string and output another string using the keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I'm trying to write a program that takes a string of letters and translates them into a sequence of braille, where 1 is a raised bump and 0 is a flat service. right now I have created a dictionary that has all of the letters of the alphabet translated into their braille letter.

```
myDict = {'a' : '100000','b': '110000','c': '100100','d': '100110','e': '100010','f': '110100','g': '110110','h':'110010','i': '010100','j':'010110','k': '101000','l': '111000','m':'101100','n': '101110','o': '101010','p': '111100','q': '111110','r': '111010','s':'011100', 't': '011110','u': '101001','v': '111001','w': '010111','x': '101101','y': '101111','z': '101011'}
```

now I'm wanting to see if there is a way that I could input a name like 'Steve' and have it output to its respective braille counterpart which would be 011100011110100010111001100010

Edit: this is what i have now.

```
myDict = {'a' : '100000','b': '110000','c': '100100','d': '100110','e': '100010','f': '110100','g': '110110','h':'110010','i': '010100','j':'010110','k': '101000','l': '111000','m':'101100','n': '101110','o': '101010','p': '111100','q': '111110','r': '111010','s':'011100', 't': '011110','u': '101001','v': '111001','w': '010111','x': '101101','y': '101111','z': '101011'}
def braille(string, myDict):
    a = ''
    for char in string:
        a.join(myDict[char])
        return a
char = str(input())
braille(char, myDict)
```

I get what is going on I just don't know what I need to put in my parameters when I call it. Also, it seems like when I run it it's not returning anything

Comment: Something like `''.join([myDict[c] for c in input_string])`

Comment: Or if you're feeling frisky: `''.join(map(myDict.get, input_string))`

Comment: @chrisz - You may have just triggered a `map` verses list comprehension war! ... and its `''.join(myDict[c] for c in input_string)` (smile).

Comment: I'd vote for the first option @chrisz. [It seems to be a bit faster](https://ideone.com/fLNB9y).

Comment: Note, passing a `list` directly to `.join` is always faster in CPython, because non-sequences are converted to  list internally.

Comment: what would we put in the parameters when we call it

Comment: Were you doing google foobar ?

Answer (score 2):

A concise function is below using the join method suggested by @Patrick Haugh

```
def braille(string, brailleDict):
    return ''.join(brailleDict[char] for char in string)
```

Use:

```
print braille('abcdefg', myDict)
```

Where myDict is the braille dictionary you have outlined.

Comment: Why use an explicit `for` loop here?

Comment: This will create a bunch of intermediate memory products (partially finished strings) that the `''.join` approach avoids.

Comment: @ChristianDean nothing wrong with a for-loop, but definitely I would avoid the `+` string in a loop anti-pattern.

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with using a `for` loop per se, @juanpa.arrivillaga. I simply asked the OP why, in this case, he was using one, since there were better options.

Comment: It was my first approach to the question, I now know the join() method is a better solution. Thank you

Comment: `join` is far, far superior to the `for` loop (which should be listed second, if not removed altogether).